# Can I run a Soap Request Using PHP SoapClient In Opencart 2?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, opencart

I need to process a Soap Request inside opencart 2, I built the soap request in a normal PHP file to start with and placed this in the root of my website, after I got that working I thought it would just be a case to add a function inside opencart 2 and place the soap request code in there. Now i can call the right function and the method containing the soap request but as soon as opencart try's to process the new soap client line which is :-

```
$newclient = new SoapClient('https://example.com/catalog/controller/soap/efiWSDL27.wsdl');
```

I get the following error:-

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request POST /index.php.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

If I comment out this line, then the rest of the function runs ok, apart from anything that relies on the soap request.

So to be clear Im getting this error before I try and call the soap request further down the function, It happens purely on the new soapclient statement.

**Do I need to specify any other parameters when I do the new soap client from within Opencart**

I know the wsdl is reachable, Im lost on this one,  like I say the exact same code will work on the same webspace in a plain php file outside of opencart. I also tried a different webservice with a remote wsdl and I still get this same error in side opencart?

please help me :)

Comment: Seriously? nobody knows this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Exactly The Right Answer, But the solution for me was to use the nusoap library rather than the built-in soapclient in PHP and then it worked perfectly.